# how to run gtest unit in groovy

Tags: ros, catkin, gtest, unit-testing, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have built laser_geometry with catkin, no error. as discription in ros wiki about gtest. It will generate a runable test. But there is nothing.
How do I test the package? Someone has used this package? Help me please. Thanks a lot!

in the CMakeList.txt , has added **catkin_add_test()**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57087/how-to-run-gtest-unit-in-groovy/) by [hawk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4229/hawk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-05**:
Is there a **test_depend** for **gtest** in your package.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you joq. I have found answer in your blog space  and run test successful.
I have to execute "make tests" in ~/catkin_ws/build, not ~/catkin_ws, if not, it will prompt :
(make: *** 没有规则可以创建目标“tests”。 停止。)

by the way. "test_depend" is not needed. Thanks again for your reply!

---

Originally posted by [hawk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4229/hawk/) with karma: 36 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1